# Compare JSONObject and Object with same .toString content

Tags: java, android, json

In my Android app, I have a JSONObject (let's name it **jo**) and I have a simple Java Object (let's name it **oo**). They both contain exactly the same string if I call **.toString** method on them.
But when I compare that strings with **.equals()** method I never get **true**. Also when I print the **hashCode** -s of that strings, they are always different. I don't understand why..

`System.out.println(jo.toString())` and `System.out.println(oo.toString())` print **exactly** the same values. But:

`jo.toString().equals(oo.toString())` **never** returns **true**.

`jo.toString().trim().equals(oo.toString().trim())` also **never** returns **true**.

`System.out.println(jo.toString().hashCode())` and `System.out.println(oo.toString().hashCode())` **always** print **different** hashCodes.

I just don't understand why ?

Comment: Can you please post the content of jo and oo.

Comment: show us what you see - show us the code - show us the println outputs... pls give details when posting questions. Some of the guys here are real good, but none are mind readers ;)

Comment: hashCodes of two objects must be equal if the objects are equal, however, if two objects are unequal, the hashCode can still be equal. Do not relay on hashcodes for equals. In your case jo.toString() and oo.toString() will not same character sets. There may be spaces missing. Plz check for it.

Comment: The result of toString method is class specific, and so does not always guarantee expected result

Comment: I have compared every character of println output and they are the same, so I think there is no need to copy past them here, you will see the same thing as I did, they are the same). I have tried to make my question as general as possible without losing its meaning, so other people in the future may benefit from this conversation without trying to understand my special staff. This is why you don't see my code or the outputs of my printlns ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be blank spaces that differ or other crazy stuff that the eye does not catch, without seeing the strings it's hard to tell.
I would run a simple check:

```
char[] first  = s1.toCharArray();
char[] second = s2.toCharArray();

int length = s1.length;
int pos = 0;
boolean equal = true;

for(int i = 0; i < length && equal; i++) {
        if (first[i] == second[i]) {
            pos++;    
        } else {
            equal == false;    
        }
}
System.out.println("equal=" + equal + ", position of non-equal=" + pos);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I check this way, they are equal to each other, I get true in println. I will use this method to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are making a string out of the JSON object not the String it contains, you have to extract the string from the position in your array or object. Example(don't know how your JSON is built):

```
    String s = jo.getString("theOneString");
    String ss = oo.getString("theOneString");
    Log.d(TAG, "bool equals: " s.equalsIgnoreCase(ss))
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I need to compare the whole content of the object, there is not one field in JSONObject that I want to compare, and I don't wont to compare each of the fields separately. The answer of aviad seems to solve my problem.

Comment: aha, misunderstood your question, glad it worked out